# object value matches any in array indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am currently writing a bit of a side project. This should be quite simple. 
I have an array of values that looks like

```
values = ["Snow","Rain"];
```

I am trying to check an object property value against all values in the array. If there is only one value it works perfect and I assume that is because indexOf only checks against a single value. I am wondering what I should be using instead?

```
$scope.weather = payload.data;
                var len = $scope.weather.length;
                $scope.year = {};
                for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    if($scope.weather[i].Events !== null){
                      if($scope.weather[i].Events.indexOf(values) > -1){
                        if(!$scope.year[$scope.weather[i].year]){
                            $scope.year[$scope.weather[i].year] = 1;
                        }else{
                        $scope.year[$scope.weather[i].year] += 1;

                        }

                    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I figure there's got to be a built in function for something like this.

Comment: @zerkms, there is a loop in the code.  Jared, have you tried singlestepping in the browser and iinspecting the values as you go along ?

Comment: @RohitGupta "there is a loop in the code" --- JS allows to have *multiple* loops. It's fine to have more than one if you need it.

Comment: I got it to work with a loop but it makes it a bit cluttered.

Comment: @JaredMarkShillingburg put it into a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (ES5):

```
values.some(function(v) {
    return $scope.weather[i].Events.indexOf(v) > -1;
})
```

as a drop in replacement for the incorrect:

```
$scope.weather[i].Events.indexOf(values) > -1
```